# Dictionary.Contains at specific start index

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, contains

How can I check whether the dictionary contains a value starting from predefined key? For example, I want to search the dictionary only **after** a specific key, not starting the search from the first one.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you assuming keys are stored in the order they were added? How would you define "after a key"?

Comment: Using a dictionary any other way than just looking up by key, sounds like dictionary abuse and calls for another type of collection. But as @itsme86 says: please elaborate a bit more on what you exactly mean.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) states about `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`: "The order in which the items are returned is undefined." While this refers to the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` implementation, the statement is generally valid for the order of elements in a dictionary. It is **undefined**. Therefore, terms such as **first** or **after** are meaningless with respect to keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Also, changing the font weight of unclear words to **bold** does not make them any clearer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you need is an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), which offers control over insertion order. Here's an example, also containing some search speed statistics.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var startIndex = 1000000; // 00:00:00.0004876
            //var startIndex = 1;     // 00:00:00.0152319

            var searchedKey = "1";

            OrderedDictionary orderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();

            //populate
            for (int i = 2; i < 1000002; i++)
            {
                orderedDictionary.Add(i.ToString(), "X");
            }
            orderedDictionary.Add("1", "A");

            //copy the keys
            String[] keys = new String[1000006];
            orderedDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

            //measure the time with a System.Diagnostics.StopWatch
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            for (int i = startIndex; i < orderedDictionary.Count; i++)
            {
                if (keys[i] == searchedKey)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(orderedDictionary[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that a dictionary is the best thing for you to use in this situation because (as previously stated) the order is NOT guaranteed.  However, if you use a `List<>` you can get the behavior you are looking for.  Like this example:

```
        var items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A", "1"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("B", "2"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("C", "3"));
        var results = items.Skip(1).Take(1).ToList();

        MessageBox.Show(results[0].Key + " " + results[0].Value);
```

In this example the resulting message shown would be "B 2" using the `Skip` and `Take` methods.  It "skips" the first "1" and "takes" the next "1";

**EDIT** (Refactored to use KeyValuePair list rather than string.)

Comment: I don't see how this is useful to the OP as I doubt he would be using a Dictionary if he didn't need the inherent key/value selection. You might suggest he try a List<KeyValuePair<type, type>> with your method instead.

Comment: @JesseCarter Good recommendation.  I was trying to simply show the Skip and Take functionality but your suggestion may be more useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a regular `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then you can't, unless you first sort it.

What you can do is to use either [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), both sort by key.